# Format number with leading spaces if digit not available

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin XAMl/WPF, I tried to use StringFormat but it didn't work. 
I need to bind an integer value which ranges from 1 digit to 3 digits but need to have leading spaces so that UI doesn't change on value change.

I tried following in [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_1), but it didn't work:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding JpegQualityValue, StringFormat={}{0,3:###}}" />
```

And Following works:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding FormattedJpegQualityValue}" />
```

with extra code behind:

```
    public string FormattedJpegQualityValue
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0,3:###}", JpegQualityValue);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way, by which this can work in XAML only and do not need to modify code behind just for format?
I've added WPF tag/keywords, as most of code is similar to WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `StringFormat` expression to `StringFormat='{0,3:###}'`.

The value provided to a StringFormat should be within single quotations to prevent the Xaml expression parser getting confused by `{` and `}` characters.

See the [Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PadLeft`:

```
JpegQualityValue.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0');
```

Otherwise, you could use

You could use a converter, which is what is usually done in WPF when you need to play with your values

```
<Label Text="{Binding FormattedJpegQualityValue, 
              Converter={StaticResource ZeroesConverter}}"}" />

// obviously, following is not in your xaml.
public class ZeroesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // put logic here. 
        // convert int to string, look at length, append zeroes, or use the string formatter if you want
        value.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0');
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // throw some exception. you don't need this
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it but, it will again add code into CodeBehind classes, which was avoided. I was looking for a way it can be done purely in XAML without changing CodeBehind.

Comment: @Vishnu yeah, nothing comes to mind to do it from XAML at the moment, maybe somebody else will have an idea.